# Polars Technical Indicators and Strategy

Tags: python, python-polars, technical-indicator

As pandas is very slow trying to use Polars. I was able to calculate the SMA and MACD values to the data frame( Not sure the values are correct for now). How can I convert the said code to use with  Polars.

```
def implement_macd_strategy(df):    
buy_price = []
sell_price = []
macd_signal = []
signal = 0

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['MACD_8_21_5'][i] > df['MACDs_8_21_5'][i]:
        if signal != 1:
            buy_price.append(df['Close'][i])
            sell_price.append(np.nan)
            signal = 1
            macd_signal.append(signal)
        else:
            buy_price.append(np.nan)
            sell_price.append(np.nan)
            macd_signal.append(0)
    elif df['MACD_8_21_5'][i] < df['MACDs_8_21_5'][i]:
        if signal != -1:
            buy_price.append(np.nan)
            sell_price.append(df['Close'][i])
            signal = -1
            macd_signal.append(signal)
        else:
            buy_price.append(np.nan)
            sell_price.append(np.nan)
            macd_signal.append(0)
    else:
        buy_price.append(np.nan)
        sell_price.append(np.nan)
        macd_signal.append(0)
        
df['buy_price MACD'] = buy_price
df['sell_price MACD'] = sell_price
df['signal MACD'] = signal

        
return df
```

Comment: Can you add an example input dataframe and the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

The iterative approach as in the original post isn't best for Polars. To fully take advantage of Polars, let's use the patterns that emerge when constructing the  `signal` column.

We can calculate the `signal` column in this way, all in parallelizable Polars expressions:

- Generate the sign of the difference of the two columns with `(pl.col('MACD_8_21_5') - pl.col('MACDs_8_21_5')).sign()`. This will generate a column of `-1` and `1`s (potentially `0` but it looks like you're not worried about equal values here, assuming it's a floating point column).
- Note that `signal` is `0` on any consecutive `-1`s and `1`s after the first one.
- [`rle_id`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rle_id.html#polars.Expr.rle_id) is a fairly recent addition to polars that maps a column's values to a unique integer ID for each "run" of the same value in a column.
- Further note that [`is_first_distinct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.is_first_distinct.html#polars-expr-is-first-distinct) gives a mask that will be `True` once, then all `False`s [`over`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.over.html#polars.Expr.over) each run.
- We are now ready to create the `signal` column with a [`when`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html#polars.when) expression (Polars' equivalent of if/else branches), zeroing out the non-first rows of each run.

Once we have the correct signal column, filling in the buy/sell price columns is one more simple `when-then` expression.

Example with dummy values (random seed set for reproduciblity):

```py
random.seed(1)

df = pl.from_dict(
    {
        'MACD_8_21_5': [random.uniform(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(20)],
        'MACDs_8_21_5': [random.uniform(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(20)],
        'Close' : [random.uniform(10000, 100000) for _ in range(20)]
    }
)

raw_signal_expr = (pl.col('MACD_8_21_5') - pl.col('MACDs_8_21_5')).sign()
signal_expr = (
    pl.when(raw_signal_expr.is_first_distinct().over(raw_signal_expr.rle_id()))
    .then(raw_signal_expr)
    .otherwise(0)
)

df.with_columns(
    buy_price=pl.when(signal_expr > 0).then(pl.col('Close')).otherwise(np.nan),
    sell_price=pl.when(signal_expr < 0).then(pl.col('Close')).otherwise(np.nan),
    signal=signal_expr,
)
```

```
shape: (20, 6)
┌─────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬────────┐
│ MACD_8_21_5 ┆ MACDs_8_21_5 ┆ Close        ┆ buy_price    ┆ sell_price   ┆ signal │
│ ---         ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---          ┆ ---    │
│ f64         ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ f64          ┆ i64    │
╞═════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪════════╡
│ -731.271512 ┆ -949.108278  ┆ 99328.907096 ┆ 99328.907096 ┆ NaN          ┆ 1      │
│ 694.867474  ┆ 82.824946    ┆ 87395.187592 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ 527.549238  ┆ 878.298326   ┆ 20880.096383 ┆ NaN          ┆ 20880.096383 ┆ -1     │
│ -489.861949 ┆ -237.591525  ┆ 39942.566682 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ -9.129826   ┆ -566.801206  ┆ 74933.596682 ┆ 74933.596682 ┆ NaN          ┆ 1      │
│ -101.01787  ┆ -155.766849  ┆ 74007.259273 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ 303.185945  ┆ -941.918425  ┆ 94279.652812 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ 577.446702  ┆ -556.616667  ┆ 47989.629997 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ -812.280826 ┆ -124.224813  ┆ 84703.212395 ┆ NaN          ┆ 84703.212395 ┆ -1     │
│ -943.305047 ┆ -8.375517    ┆ 70327.500977 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ 671.530208  ┆ -533.831099  ┆ 37303.165984 ┆ 37303.165984 ┆ NaN          ┆ 1      │
│ -134.465864 ┆ -538.266917  ┆ 62882.254553 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ 524.560165  ┆ -562.437925  ┆ 89423.110075 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ -995.787893 ┆ -80.793069   ┆ 86157.767659 ┆ NaN          ┆ 86157.767659 ┆ -1     │
│ -109.225612 ┆ -420.436771  ┆ 55475.543852 ┆ 55475.543852 ┆ NaN          ┆ 1      │
│ 443.080065  ┆ -957.020589  ┆ 63010.203218 ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ -542.475557 ┆ 675.155951   ┆ 13107.324714 ┆ NaN          ┆ 13107.324714 ┆ -1     │
│ 890.541391  ┆ 112.908645   ┆ 31846.597619 ┆ 31846.597619 ┆ NaN          ┆ 1      │
│ 802.854915  ┆ 284.588726   ┆ 81766.38228  ┆ NaN          ┆ NaN          ┆ 0      │
│ -938.820034 ┆ -628.187468  ┆ 47288.259937 ┆ NaN          ┆ 47288.259937 ┆ -1     │
└─────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴────────┘
```

Putting `raw_signal_expr` and `signal_expr` in variables to reuse for readability is fine - Polars will recognize the reused expressions in the query plan and auto-cache it.

Answer (score -3):

it is better in such cases to give some input and desired output for testing purposes. Can you try this and say if it is ok for you:

```
import polars as pl

def implement_macd_strategy(df):
    buy_price = pl.col("Close").apply(lambda x: pl.when(pl.col("MACD_8_21_5") > pl.col("MACDs_8_21_5")).then(x).otherwise(pl.nan()))
    sell_price = pl.col("Close").apply(lambda x: pl.when(pl.col("MACD_8_21_5") < pl.col("MACDs_8_21_5")).then(x).otherwise(pl.nan()))
    macd_signal = pl.col("MACD_8_21_5").apply(lambda x: pl.when(x > pl.col("MACDs_8_21_5")).then(1).when(x < pl.col("MACDs_8_21_5")).then(-1).otherwise(0))

    df = df.with_column(buy_price.alias("buy_price MACD"))
    df = df.with_column(sell_price.alias("sell_price MACD"))
    df = df.with_column(macd_signal.alias("signal MACD"))

    return df
```

Comment: Just for reference, I assume the downvote was due to `.apply` - you can use the expressions directly as the other answer shows. (also `.apply` has been renamed to `.map_elements`) -- `.with_column` has also since been renamed to `.with_columns`

Comment: thx for correcting!